# javascript convert string to array with checkbox for each array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, checkbox

please see the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JWPZh/1/)

I want output check-box for each array.

1. how to create array?
2. how to add check-box with unique name to array?

Whatever is in the textbox, Separate words and convert to check-box

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".step1_btn").click(function () {
        var text = $(".source").text();
        text = text.replace(/\W+/g, ',');
        $('.splited').html(text);
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<textarea class="source">Jusf to clarify, I will to have strings of varying</textarea>
<button type="button" class="step1_btn">Display Date</button>
<div id="demo" class="splited"></div>
```

Comment: What's the error that you're getting?

Comment: _"how to create array?"_ - You haven't told us what data you want to put in the array.

Comment: @taylorc93 Not an error. I do not know how to write.

Comment: @nnnnnn Whatever is in the textarea. Separate word

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are trying to split the words in the textbox into separate checkboxes, this will do that:

```
$(".step1_btn").click(function () {

    var text = $(".source").text();
    var parts = text.split(" ");

    for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
        var input = "<input type='checkbox' value='" + i + "'/>";
        var cbLabel = "<label>" + parts[i] + "</label>";
        $("#demo").append(input + cbLabel);
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/JWPZh/2/

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like

```
 $(".step1_btn").click(function () {

        var text = $(".source").text();

        text = text.replace(/\W+/g, ',');

        $('.splited').html(text);

        $.each(text.split(','), function (index, value) {
            // Check if it is already added
            if (!$("#" + value).length) {
               // Dont exist add new one
               $("#demo").append("<input id=" + value +  " type='checkbox' value='"+ value+"' />" + value );
            }
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I interpretted your question as follows:

1. Split the text in the textarea element using a single empty space as a delimiter.
2. Use the resultant array to create input and respective label elements.

If this is the case, then the code below should satisfy your need.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.step1_btn').on('click', function () {
        var counter = 0,
            fragment = document.createDocumentFragment(),
            parts = $('.source').text().split(' '),
            length = parts.length,
            input,
            label;

        for (; counter < length; counter += 1) {
             label = document.createElement('label');
             label.innerHTML = parts[counter];
             label.setAttribute('for', parts[counter]);
             input = document.createElement('input');
             input.setAttribute('type', 'checkbox');
             input.setAttribute('name', parts[counter]);
             fragment.appendChild(label);
             fragment.appendChild(input);
        }
        $(document.getElementById('demo')).append(fragment);
    });
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stavarotti/LnUn7/)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is what you're after?

```
var source = $(".source").text()
var array = []
$.each( source.split(/\W+/g), function(i, v){
    array.push( $("<input type=checkbox id='"+v+"' value='"+v+"'/>") )
})
```

`array` will contain an `<input>` element for each word in the source string